# Why Doesn't Applescript Exit After Background Shell Job?

Tags: applescript

I can created an (very) simple applescript app to run Firefox background & exit.  (The reason is I have different profiles for work & home).  My script is basically:

> do shell script
>   "/Applications/firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
>   -no-remote  -P 'Personal' &"

It works, but the script/app doesn't exit until I quit Firefox.  How can I fix that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to redirect stdout and stderr somewhere. The **do shell script** command knows that the pipes it setup for the program's stdout and stderr are still open, so it waits for them to be closed.

```
do shell script "/Applications/firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -no-remote -P 'Personal' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```